# Derivative of square of skew symmetric matrix times a vector wrt the argument of the skew symmetric argument

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

I've got a funny derivative that is giving me problems.  It mostly has to do with the skew-symmetric matrix and trying to take a derivative with respect to what is inside the operator.

I've defined the skew-symmetric operator as

$$ \lfloor \omega \rfloor = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &  -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
\omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\ -\omega_y & \omega_x &0 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\omega = \begin{bmatrix} \omega_x & \omega_y & \omega_z \end{bmatrix} ^\top $

I can solve the case below, because of the identity $ \lfloor \omega \rfloor v = -\lfloor v \rfloor \omega  $

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \lfloor \omega \rfloor v = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} -\lfloor v \rfloor \omega \\
= -\lfloor v \rfloor
$$

but what if I have omega skew squared?
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \lfloor \omega \rfloor \lfloor \omega \rfloor v  $$

I can't seem to manipulate this in a way that I can find the derivative.  And it also seems that the chain rule is not doing what I wanted.  I've tried the following:

$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \lfloor \omega \rfloor \lfloor \omega \rfloor v = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \lfloor \omega \rfloor \lfloor \omega \rfloor v \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial \lfloor \omega \rfloor v}\left( \lfloor \omega \rfloor \lfloor \omega \rfloor v \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \lfloor \omega \rfloor v \\
= -\lfloor \omega \rfloor \lfloor v \rfloor
$$

but numerical differentiation doesn't agree.

I think I'm confused about what the skew-symmetric matrix really means.  It feels like a vector, pretending to be a matrix and there must be some be rules when dealing with that I'm not following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer using the [Vector Triple Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html).

$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \left( \omega \times \omega \times v   \right) = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \left( \omega(\omega ^\top v) - v(\omega^\top \omega ) \right) \\
= I(\omega^\top v) + \omega v^\top - 2v\omega^\top
$$

I confirmed this with numerical differentiation, and it seems to check out -  [python script](https://gist.github.com/superjax/c4dcc57babdc59096d3163da7dad93d1)

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\rc#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\rc{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$For ease of typing, let me use the notation
$$\eqalign{
 W &= \lfloor w \rfloor,
 \qquad V &= \lfloor v \rfloor,
 \qquad F &= \lfloor f \rfloor
\\
}$$
As you noted, the first function is easy to deal with
$$\eqalign{
&f= Wv \;=\; \LR{w\times v} \;=\; -\rc Vw \qquad \\
&\grad fw = -\rc V\gradLR ww \;\equiv\; -V \\
}$$
The second function is a bit trickier
$$\eqalign{
&g = W^2v \;=\; \rc Wf \;=\; -\rc Fw \qquad \\
&\grad gw
 = \rc W\gradLR fw - \rc F\gradLR ww 
 \;\equiv\; -\LR{WV + F} \\
}$$

Comment: I understand the approach, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to match numerical methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was led astray by a faulty assumption $$\Big(\frac{\partial W^2}{\partial w}\Big)\,v \neq \frac{\partial (W^2v)}{\partial w}$$ My answer concerns the LHS, but your question was about the RHS. Your triple product approach below is the correct one.

Comment: That makes sense.  I suppose I should have made that more clear in my question.  Thanks!